# PuTTY 0.67 unable to SSH into CentOS 7

Tags: virtualbox, putty, centos-7, sshd

When trying to ssh into a Centos 7 VM using PuTTY I'm getting "Access Denied". Here are the things that I tried based on other solved answers:

- unchecked GSSAPI
- set PermitRootLogin to yes
- tried sshing to the same ip with that username/password from other machines (it works)

It only seems like direct PuTTY login isn't working which GSSAPI unchecking should have fixed, also this bug was supposed to be fixed by 0.67 version anyway, what else could cause this?

Comment: Have you tried disabling your anti virus and or firewall temporarily?

Comment: *"PuTTY 0.67 unable"* - Does that imply that any other SSH client *"is able"*?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in my specific case the problem was the local network, the IP that the Centos VM got was the same as another machine on the network, and on some systems the IP resolved to that VM and on others to the original machine, which made it seem that I was able to login with other clients but not PuTTY, when really it was the machine itself (actually DNS shenanigans)